# How to clear the Subitems on a ListViewItem without clearing the Text?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

i am trying to clear, and re-add, the [`SubItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx) of a [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) in .net.

```
private void RefreshItem(ListViewItem item)
{
   item.Text = accountNumber;

   item.SubItems.Clear(); //in case there are any
   item.SubItems.Add(name);    
   item.SubItems.Add(address);
   item.SubItems.Add(phone);
   item.SubItems.Add(workphone);
   item.SubItems.Add(email);
   item.SubItems.Add(idType);
   item.SubItems.Add(idNumber);
   item.SubItems.Add(idExpires);
   ...
}
```

But clearing the subitems also clears the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text.aspx).

> **Note:** Paradoxically, clearing `SubItems` also clears the `Text`, but adding `SubItems` does not also add the `Text`.

The problem also appears when i only want to update the SubItems:

```
private void RefreshItem(ListViewItem item)
{
   item.SubItems.Clear(); //in case there are any
   item.SubItems.Add(location);    
   item.SubItems.Add(date);
   item.SubItems.Add(cashier);
   item.SubItems.Add(totalBuyAmount);
   item.SubItems.Add(totalSellAmount);
   item.SubItems.Add(currencyCode);
   item.SubItems.Add(exchangeRate);
   item.SubItems.Add(isVip);
   ...
}
```

How can i [Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitemcollection.clear.aspx) the [SubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx) of a [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx), but not clear the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitemcollection.clear.aspx)?

Comment: Can you not store the `Text` in a local variable, clear the `SubItems` and then re-set the `Text`? Perhaps not the most ideal solution.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you'd want to clear the subitems but not the text associated with them.

Comment: @John i think you might mis-understand. `Text` is the text of the `ListItem` itself. The ListItem can then have SubItems. i want to clear the ListItem.SubItems collection, but leave the ListItem.Text property.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: Try what adrift said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, I've never noticed that behavior.  If there isn't an easier way, I would loop through and remove all `SubItem`s with an `Index` greater than `0`.  The `SubItem` with index `0` is the one corresponding to the `ListViewItem.Text`.

For reference, see this note on the [`SubItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx) property:

> The first subitem in the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection is
>   always the item that owns the subitems. When performing operations on
>   subitems in the collection, be sure to reference index position 1
>   instead of 0 to make changes to the first subitem.

Comment: i added an extension method with a `(boolean workCorrectly)` parameter. It clears `ListViewItem.SubItems` collection, while leaving the `ListViewItem.Text` property alone.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the SubItem's text instead of removing and re-adding?

Comment: Because i don't know how many subitems are there when the function starts

Answer (score 0):

When refreshing data in datagridviews, listviews and similar widgets, it can be very useful to use SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() around your updates.  This will allow you to do any cleanup or manipulation you need without the user seeing the intermediate states or lots of flicker.  I have used this to help with maintaining sort ordering over a refresh and similar problems:

```
public void OnRefreshButtonClicked(object *sender)
{
    myListView.SuspendLayout();

    foreach (ListViewItem itm in myListView.Items)
    {
        RefreshItem(itm);
    }

    myListView.ResumeLayout();
}
```